# Django and admin templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have created a Django project and packaged it using py2exe. It also uses cherrypy as a webserver for the project to get served. I would like to ask a question. My executable django app can't find the admin templates. So i was wondering how does Django locate the admin templates? Do i need to copy them from django/contrib/admin/templates to my templates folder?

The error i get when i execute (using the derived exe) my programm is

```
TemplateDoesNotExist 
Exception Value:admin/login.html django
```

that is when i visit the admin backend of my project. If i run it normaly through manage.py
admin works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The admin templates are located in `django\contrib\admin\templates` - you'll have to include them or copy them as is to a `template` folder in your main app.

An other option would be to put them in a seperate dierctory and add this directory to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in your `settings.py`. This might be a good option for you because it keeps the original files separated from your project templates.